# Gizmo replaced with Arrows when using shortcuts (size, rotation, position)

Tags: shortcut

So this one is hard to describe so I'll use screenshots

This appears when I use Size tool shortcut <kbd>S</kbd>

[image: This appears when I use Size tool shortcut "S"]

[image: This is when I click on size tool]

This is when I click on size tool

This happens with all of the main shortcut tools
I tried factory reset on preferences. New scenes. I even tried to repair the app from the original install.

Does anybody have a clue what this is about?

Comment: I don't think anything's amiss here - I think that's how it's supposed to be. When you scale with a shortcut, you can define the scaling axis by using a letter (ex: x, y, z), and define the extent (distance) by dragging the mouse - therefore there is no need for a gizmo. The gizmo appears when you choose (click on) the scale tool because some people just choose to work that way - scaling by grabbing the handles instead of typing an axis. In other words, they're not supposed to be the same - the toolbar tools offer a slightly different "look" for many of the same operations.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer by itself, Christopher.

Comment: Right, so apparently it's a behaviour tied in with using the Blender shortcuts instead of Industry standard. Thanks Christopher for clearing this up. I wanted to switch binding to be able to follow tutorials more easily, but it was my undoing :D